# how to allow javascript to communicate with flash (Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, swfobject, externalinterface

I'm trying to send a simple test message from javascript to flash, but I'm getting the error:

```
Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method "listenToJS"
```

I've read a number of questions on this on stack, but I feel like either the browser is not getting the proper reference to my flash object, or within my actionscript I am not putting my flash function in the proper place.

So within html I am embedding flash with SWFObj:

```
<div id="flash_content">
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="1280" height="800" id="tourFlash" name="pano" class="pano">
        <param name="movie" value="VRDemo.swf" />
        <param name="menu" value="false" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="VRDemo.swf" width="1280" height="800" class="pano">
            <param name="menu" value="false" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
            <param name="allownetworking" value="all" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="zoom=null&amp;pan=null&amp;sound=null" />
        <!--<![endif]-->
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
            </a>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
</div>

<script>

var flashObj; 

$(document).ready(function(){

    flashObj = document.getElementById('tourFlash');

    $('#interface').click(function(){
        console.log('click');
        talkToFlash();
    });
});

function talkToFlash(){
    flashObj.listenToJS('hello from js');
}

function listenFromFlash(flashMessage){
    console.log(message);
}
</script>
```

The click handler is triggered, but here I get the error. My flash file uses a document class, and within the document class is the public function. Flash is structured like this:

```
package com.company.vr {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*; 
    import com.greensock.*;
    import com.greensock.easing.*;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.system.Security;

    Security.allowDomain("*");

     public class VR_TestDocument extends MovieClip {
            public function VR_TestDocument() {
              ExternalInterface.addCallback("talkToFlash", listenToJS);
            }


            public function listenToJS(message){
              trace ("from js: " + message);
              var flashMessage = message + " flash";
              ExternalInterface.call("listenFromFlash", flashMessage);
            }
     }
}
```

---UPDATE---

It looks like External Interface doesn't like SWFObject for some reason. If I switch to the method of embedding that Flash used in this example:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback()

it works, but I feel like swfobject is the best way to embed flash. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: have you seen this? http://www.blago.net/coding/snippets/getting-data-into-flash-swfobject-2-and-externalinterface-as3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you embeded flash in html as your code above, note, that second tag **object** also has to contain attribute **id**, corrected code is here:

```
<div id="flash_content">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="1280" height="800" id="tourFlash" name="pano" class="pano">
    <param name="movie" value="VRDemo.swf" />
    <param name="menu" value="false" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="VRDemo.swf" width="1280" height="800" class="pano" id="tourFlash1">
        <param name="menu" value="false" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="allownetworking" value="all" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="zoom=null&amp;pan=null&amp;sound=null" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
        </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

But of course, swfobject is the best way to embed flash. Correct html code looks like:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>js</title>       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script>
            function talkToFlash(){
                document.getElementById('flash_content').listenToJS('hello from js');
            }

            var flashvars =  {};
            var params = {
                allowscriptaccess: "always"         
            }           
            var attributes =  {};
            swfobject.embedSWF("VRDemo.swf", "flash_content", "550", "400", "10.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flash_content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

--Update--

You have to select the correct flash element on the page. (Depends on the browser). As an example, here is code to get correct flashObj:

```
flashObj1 = document.getElementById('tourFlash');
flashObj2 = document.getElementById('tourFlash1');
flashObj = flashObj1.talkToFlash != undefined ? flashObj1 : flashObj2;
```

Comment: The code I used was generated by the swfobject code generator - it does not place the ID in the second instance of the object, and when I add it, it fails: http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/generator/index.html , https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/generator

Comment: I just tested given by you generator. If I set id for second tag <object> and remove the same from first - it works, try it.

Comment: But I recommend use swfobject.embedSWF() - its more flexible. swfobject.js u cad downlod from here [link](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_2_2.zip&can=2&q=)

Comment: use swfobject.getObjectById() if using static publishing. No need to add the ID in the nested object

Comment: What's this talk of having having to also assign the same id for the inner object element? Can you further explain this thing. Mustn't all elements in the DOM have _unique_ ids?
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2
- http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is my mistake in the example. Ids have to be unique. And you can decide which element to use (Depends on browser).

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be a timing issue -- Flash Player takes a little bit of time to initialize ExternalInterface, and then a little bit more time to load your SWF.  Your example code is running on DOMReady, which is NOT a guarantee that the SWF has loaded or that ExternalInterface has initialized within Flash Player.

I recommend querying the SWF to see if it has finished loading.  There's an example (using dynamic publishing) on LearnSWFObject.com: http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/executing-javascript-when-the-swf-has-finished-loading/

UPDATE:
After re-reading your code and some other suggested answers, I noticed you're using `document.getElementById` to grab your `<object>`. When using the nested `<object>` markup, this won't work (except in IE, which uses the outer `<object>`). `swfobject.getObjectById` was specifically created to address this issue. Try editing your JS to use `swfobject.getObjectById`.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give this a shot. However, the only thing being called on document ready is a reference to flashObj, which is static (it's on the page from the start), and a click handler for the "interface" button, which is also on the page from the start. So theoretically, as long as I waited for my flash to load before clicking the button, this code should still work, right?

Comment: Theoretically, yes.  For example, you could create a link that invokes your ExternalInterface, then wait for the SWF to load before clicking the link.  If your ExternalInterface works, then you know you having a timing issue. If it doesn't work, we can look for other causes.